# Restrict App Services to Front Door using Service tag and not IP

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-front-door

I read documention from MS and other blogs-articles and I am still confused on how we can restrict access to AppServices to FrontDoor only.

According documenentation i found we need to apply IPs ACL (I do not talk about the X-FrontDoor-ID).
I follow their guidelines and found more than 100 IP to allow.

My question is why can't just use the ServiceTag as below ? Just one rule isn't enough to secure ?
[image]

Your thoughts ?
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my understanding, a service tag represents a **group of IP address** prefixes from a given Azure service. Microsoft manages the address prefixes encompassed by the service tag and automatically updates the service tag frequently. You should use that service tag `AzureFrontDoor.Backend` in the Azure App Service access restrictions unless the service tag does not match in the [Azure IP Ranges and Service Tags](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519). Read [this blog](https://henrihietala.fi/limit-access-to-your-azure-web-app-from-your-azure-front-door-only/) for more details. However, it's a rare scenario.

Comment: Thanks Nancy.I also understand that using ServiceTag is better than using list of IP. Some articles and blog keep inviting to use IP. I do not understand why ;)

Comment: Answer from MS Tech support: I can't advise you much about the third party articles. However, I can advise you that the IP and ServiceTag restrictions serve different cases. When restricting IP's you would deny or allow only that particular connection and keep in mind that there is a limit of 512 rows of IPs that you can restrict. However with service tags you can specify to allow or deny different parts of Azure. In our case the ServiceTag would be the quickest way to achieve your goal.